# when i call balance function it shows 0 all the time ? I am deploying at remix - solidity

Tags: solidity, remix

```
pragma solidity 0.4.19;

contract blackeye {
    uint public max_amount = 1000000;
    uint public total_balance_bought = 0;

    mapping(address => uint) total_balance;   

    address owneraddress;

    modifier onlyowner {
        require(owneraddress == msg.sender);
        _;
    }

    modifier can_buy_amount(uint rupee_invested) {
        require(rupee_invested + total_balance_bought <= max_amount);
        _;
    }

    function balance(address investor) external constant returns(uint) {
        return total_balance[investor];
    }

    function deposit(address creator, address investor, uint rupee_invested) external {
        if (msg.sender == address(creator)) {
            uint amount_bought = rupee_invested;
            total_balance[investor] += amount_bought;
            total_balance_bought += amount_bought;
        }
    }

    function withdraw(address creator, address investor, uint amount_sold) external {
        if (msg.sender == address(creator)) {
            total_balance[investor] -= amount_sold;
            total_balance_bought -= amount_sold;
        }
    }

    function send_money(address sender, address receiver, uint amount_send) external {
        total_balance[sender] -= amount_send;
        total_balance[receiver] += amount_send;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems.

This doesn't do anything useful.

```
if (msg.sender == address(creator))  {
```

A sender can just pass their own address into the function to make the condition `true`. I think what you want is to check that the sender is authorized to report rupees received.

You don't need this because you can make the `mapping` `public`. It gives you a "free" getter function.

```
function balance(address investor) external constant returns(uint){
    return total_balance[investor];
}
```

The withdraw function doesn't do anything because there is nothing to withdraw to. This is not dealing with Ethereum and not a standard token. In any case, a token like this "withdrawn" by sending from one account to another, which is covered by your `send` function.

Don't trust the sender. Verify. The send function should use `msg.sender` to check the balance of the sender's account.

Here's a cleaned up version you can play around with in Remix.

```
pragma solidity 0.4.19;

contract BlackEye{

    uint public initial_supply = 1000000;

    mapping(address=> uint) public balances;   

    address ownerAddress;

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(ownerAddress == msg.sender);
        _;
    }
    function BlackEye() public {
        ownerAddress = msg.sender;
        balances[address(this)] = initial_supply;
    }
    function deposit(address investor, uint rupee_invested) external onlyOwner {
        balances[investor] += rupee_invested;
        balances[address(this)] -= rupee_invested;
    }
    function send_money(address receiver , uint amount_send) external{
        require(balances[msg.sender] >= amount_send);
        balances[msg.sender] -= amount_send;
        balances[receiver] += amount_send;
    }
    function transferReserves(address receiver, uint amount) external onlyOwner {
        require(balances[address(this)] >= amount);
        balances[address(this)] -= amount;
        balances[receiver] += amount;
    }
}
```

1. Deploy the contract.
2. Copy the contract address and paste into `balances()`. See the initial supply.
3. Use the `transferReserves()` function to send some to `0xca3...` (copy). This function gives the owner access to the contract's reserve supply created in the constructor. (Using the mapping and `address(this)` simplifies the accounting).
4. Now `0xca3...` can send some to someone else.

Hope it helps.

Comment: What if two different user which are not owner and they want to transfer amount to each other? I am trying to do this functionality in send function.

Comment: They don't have to be `owner` to use `send_money`, but they need to have some tokens. They get some tokens from transactions that happened before. Initially, the only possible source is `owner` sending some `transferReserves`.